# How to change position of SKSpriteNode with SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

```
while word != ""{

    if word[word.startIndex] == "R" {

        let moveSpriteToRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x+128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1)

        sprite.run(moveSpriteToRight)

    } else if word == "D" {

        let moveSpriteToDown = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y-128), duration: 1)

        sprite.run(moveSpriteToDown)

    } else if word == "L" {

        let moveSpriteToLeft = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x-128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1)

        sprite.run(moveSpriteToLeft)

    } else if word == "U" {

        let moveSpriteToUp = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y+128), duration: 1)

        sprite.run(moveSpriteToUp) 
    }

    word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
}
```

It's part of my code.I can't use SKAction many times. For example, if the word = "ULD", then the sprite should move along the path up (U), then left (L) and down (D). And each time through the gestures the user creates new trajectories, the termination of recording gestures occurs through touchesEnded. Sprite them must perform each time. But my sprite in simulator changes position to Down in this example and all.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your actions into an array and run them as a sequence once all the checking is done

```
let actions = [SKAction]()

while word != ""{

    if word[word.startIndex] == "R" {
        actions.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x+128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1))
    }

    if word == "D" {
        actions.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y-128), duration: 1))
    } 

    if word == "L" {
        actions.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x-128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1))
    } 

    if word == "U" {
        actions.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y+128), duration: 1))
    }

    word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
}

let sequenceOfActions = SKAction.sequence([actions])
sprite.run(sequenceOfActions)
```

Comment: I think it is funny when people down vote with no explanation and do not offer any answer themselves. This answer works if you have a reason for down voting it say so.

Comment: Your welcome @Proffan . If this answered your question you should mark it as correct, so others will know this as well ;)